# Rearranging Data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've been looking through the documentation (and stack overflow) and am having trouble figuring out how rearrange a pandas data frame the way described below. I wish to have a row where there is a column name, a row name and the value of that specific row and column:

Input:

  `A B C
X 1 2 3
Y 4 5 6`

Output:

`X A 1
X B 2
X C 3
Y A 4
Y B 5
Y C 6`

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Look into the DataFrame.pivot method

Answer (score 1):

You can stack the data frame.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,4], 'B': [2,5], 'C': [3,6]}, index=['X', 'Y'])

df_stacked = df.stack()
```

Or if you don't want the letters to be in the index, you can do:

```
df_stacked = df.stack().reset_index()
```